# Is event sourcing an enhanced pattern of choreography-based SAGA pattern?

Tags: apache-kafka, redis, architecture, microservices, saga

These days I am researching the Microservice inter-service communication patterns. So during my research, I found that there are two patterns called SAGA and event sourcing. But I couldn't find a resource on the internet to learn the difference between the two patterns. I mean I know event sourcing will capture the history of the event with the aid of an event store. So as per my understandings, I feel that event sourcing is like an extended version of choreography-based SAGA pattern. So I need to clarify is my argument acceptable or not. I will attach sample diagrams of the two patterns which I found on the internet below. Please use those diagrams during any of your explanations.

[image: Choreography based SAGA Implementation]

[image: Event Sourcing]

[References](https://www.confluent.io/resources/kafka-summit-2020/redis-and-kafka-simplifying-advanced-design-patterns-within-microservices-architectures/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The two are compatible patterns that address different problems,  Sagas handle workflow processes where as event sourcing addresses how state is stored.  Sagas provide a mechanism for handling a multi-step process and rolling back should steps fail (like a workflow).  Where as Event Sourcing is the process of encoding the state of an entity by recording all its past changes.

### Sagas

Lets say we are booking a holiday, we need to book flights, a hotel and hire a car.  each of these processes is handled by a different microservice.

We could create a microservice named BookingSaga  which would be responsible for keeping track of the state of each booking.  When we make a booking the BookingSaga service would

- book the hotel
- book the flight
- book the car

these can reply in any order, but if any one fails the BookingSaga would then begin a rollback and cancel any that had already been booked.

https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html

### Event Sourcing

Event sourcing keeps track of the state of some entity by recording the changes that have happened to it.

- Object A Name changed to "dave"
- Object A Age Changed to 3
- Object A Named changed to "sue"

So we can see that Object A has a name of "sue" and an Age of 3 at the end of all the events.  https://microservices.io/patterns/data/event-sourcing.html